# Why can't plot the point with format string '-'?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Draw a line with format string `-`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=[3,4]
y=[4,5]
plt.plot(x,y,"-")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Why can't draw a point with format string `-`:

[image]

Why no point shown with `-` in the graph?

Comment: In matplotlib the format string "-" specifies a solid line. You can see here all the linestyles: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

Comment: Try `plt.plot(x, y, marker='$-$')`. Check more markers: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers

Comment: @Joao_PS nice job, you wasted my 20minutes of research with a one liner ;-)

Comment: in any case plt.plot(x, y, marker='$-$') doesnt seem to work , marker ='$-$' is a good hint though ;-). To be clear it does work but you won't see it try with plt.plot(x, y, marker='$+$')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

my attempt:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=[3,4,5,6,7,8]
y=[4,5,6,7,8,9]


plt.scatter(x,y, marker = '$-$', color ='black', linewidths = 3)

plt.show()
```

result:

[image]

its like bold character because of `linewidths = 3`

with `linewidths = 1` or non using the keyword argument you'll get more like  '-'

[image]

using, as suggested by @Joao_PS, `plt.plot(x, y, marker='$-$')`

works to but the '-' char will be covered by the line create by default by `plot.plot` func. You could see it better using `plt.plot(x, y, marker='$+$')`, see picture below:

[image]

for better explanation have a look at documentation about markers :https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers